# Topological Space in which every compact subset is metrizable

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, terminology

Is there an (more or less) established name for the class of topological spaces in which every compact subset is metrizable? This is true for example in (LF)-spaces (inductive limits of Frechet-spaces) [see for example the article "Metrizability of precompact subsets in (LF)-spaces" by Cascales/ Orihuela].

Answer (score 2):

There is, but the area of math that it was studied in is basically dead and multiple terms were used to describe these and related spaces.  Your spaces are called KM-spaces, derived from the (perhaps tongue-in-cheek?) more thoroughly studied KFC-spaces, which were sometimes instead called Kelley Spaces, or $k$-spaces, or $k'$-spaces.  So it's a mess.  I would not expect the typical topologist to be familiar with the term.

F. Siwiec, KM-spaces and km-covering mappings, Not. Amer. Math. Soc.
18 (1971), 1109-1110 #71T-G200.

https://www.jstor.org/stable/2037385

https://www.jstor.org/stable/44236412 (historical exposition)